# Event delegation from template on an iPad in Sproutcore framework

Tags: ipad, sproutcore, event-delegation

I am working on iPad web application(not a native application) and am using the Sproutcore framework. I have a button defined in a .template file and is defined as:

{{view Octopus.ButtonView content="action_ChangePassword" targetBinding=".parentView.parentView.changePasswordTarget" actionBinding=".parentView.parentView.changePasswordAction" }}

changePasswordAction is defined in the view page but the function that it is binded with doesn't get triggered on an iPad. However the same function is triggered on the Desktop web application without a code-change. May I know if there is a different way for event-delegation from .template files on iPad as compared to desktop web applications?